# Hydrostatic ballhead -really worth it?

Tags: tripod-heads, ball-head

I'm looking at [Manfrotto 468MGRC2 Magnesium Hydrostatic Ballhead](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/368325-REG/Manfrotto_468MGRC2_468MGRC2_Magnesium_Hydrostatic_Ballhead.html) which justifies that "using a hydraulic system" is better because it locks better the camera+lens (according to the manufacturer).

How significant is this difference (compared with a good mechanical ballhead) in the real world?

Comment: 468MGRC2 Marketing blurb: `Using hydraulics instead of a mechanical system` .... *What*? A Hydraulic system **is** a mechanical system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between the 468MGRC4 and [488RC4](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/272780-REG/Manfrotto_488RC4_488RC4_Midi_Ball_Head.html), the difference is *notable*. The tightening of the Hydrostatic head is very smooth and applies even pressure which makes the camera stay in the same exact position.

With the standard head, there is a slight drift in the order of one or two degrees as you tighten. When I purchased my ballhead I got the standard and eventually learned to adjust by slightly overshooting the vertical angle of the camera. I do it instinctively now but I wish I bought the hyrdrostatic head which I was unable to afford at the time.

As with everything, this matters only if it is important to you. Personally I am a maniac about composition and use my 100% coverage viewfinder to its fullest with rarely room for a shift (fill the frame I was told :) of even one degree. My primary cameras can also correct this by shifting their sensor, so if I end up not perfectly aligned, I can fix it without moving the head.

Comment: What camera shifts the sensor to adjust framing?

Comment: @dpollitt The Pentax K-5, K-5 II, K-5 IIs, K-7. It can shift horizontally, vertically and tilt. There is a remarkable leeway in shift and 2 degrees of tilt in 1/4 degree increments either way. It's quite enough to adjust for imperfect camera placement.

Comment: That is nuts. No idea that technology for that existed.

Comment: @dpollitt - Digital cameras are awesome, that's why I spend so much time with them :) and sometimes I  miss obscure features which companies are not good at advertising or work only in certain combinations of circumstances. With the more sophisticated models, I often run out of time to try all the features. I have a D4 here now and I hope I'll get to try the built-in HTTP server (!!!) before having to return it.